# State of the art in multi-modal command recognition

Tags: reference-request, speech-recognition

I'm currently researching various [fusion methods](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/M_Hossain5/publication/220460981_Multimodal_fusion_for_multimedia_analysis_a_survey/links/0fcfd50eae97fad470000000.pdf) in a multi-modal (video, audio, identity, user position and gesture) human-computer interaction environment (think in terms of a smart-home system). What is the current state of the art in this field and what fusion methods do they use?

The most recent publication I found was a PhD thesis that relied on lip reading, but I don't think this methodology is reasonable in the type of wide environment I'm considering.

Additionally, I found [this publication](http://e-archivo.uc3m.es/bitstream/handle/10016/18626/Multimodal_CaS_2013_ps.pdf?sequence=1) which fuses various channels into "acts", but this seems to focus semantic-level fusion, which is seems simplistic.